# Simple BPEL Error

Tags: java, bpel

I have developed a very simple BPEL process. It consist of receiveIinput, assign and replyoutput. When i test this process through web services explorer or SOAP UI, i always get the below error.

I put deploy.xml,.bpel and ...Artifacts.wsdl file in ode\WEB-INF\processes\hellobpel folder.

```
- <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
- <soapenv:Body>
- <soapenv:Fault>
  <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
  <faultstring xmlns:axis2ns122="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable">axis2ns122:selectionFailure</faultstring>
  <detail />
  </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: We can't determine why you're getting an Exception without seeing any of the code that's causing the exception.

Comment: A `bpel:selectionFailure` is pretty specific. However, to tell the exact xpath expression that is causing the problem, I need to have a look at your BPEL and WSDL files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from the [Apache ODE FAQ](http://ode.apache.org/faq.html):

> Q. My process fails with a selectionFailure; What can I do?
>
> A. BPEL expects a single element to be selected when evaluating  and  expressions, and a selectionFailure fault is thrown if zero or more than one element are selected.

So I guess that the output variable is not initialized and you point to an element in the to-expression that is not (yet) existing.